# Update Select table

Tags: mysql

I have the following Query :

```
UPDATE (Select * FROM 
(SELECT A.messung,A.Sensor, A.wert FROM datenmatrix as A 
LEFT JOIN (Select B.sensor FROM datenmatrix as B group by sensor) as C 
on A.sensor=C.sensor where A.Sensor=1 order by Sensor) AS P)AS V 
SET V.wert=1 where V.messung=1 and V.Sensor=1;
```

I'm getting the error :

```
"ERROR 1288 (HY000): The target table V of the UPDATE is not updatable"
```

How can i change my Query so that it works?
Do i need to use Update? Or can i use something else to change the column of the table ?

Thank you by advance

Comment: your question is unclear. What exactly are you trying to update? Show samples, expected output and clarify what you actually want to do

Comment: Can you explain what you're actually trying to achieve? Tell us some sample data in you table(s) and what output you expect.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED based on comment from the OP

Nope, in sql you can only use the `update` statement to change a field's value directly in a table. If you want to change certain values in the output of the query, you need to perform those calculations within the select itself.

Still, I think you are overcomplicating the query. I do not see any point of using the subqueries, not even the join. In the `(Select B.sensor FROM datenmatrix as B group by sensor) as C` subquery you just select the distinct `sensor` values from the `datenmatrix` table and you want to left join this on the `datenmatrix` table again. This does not make any sense. I believe the query below is all you need:

```
SELECT messung, sensor, if(messung=1,1,wert) as wert
FROM datenmatrix 
WHERE Sensor=1;
```

Comment: Ok if i can't use the update statement for that is there any other statement that i can use?

Comment: Yes i read your answer but i isn' that i want. I don't want to alter the table. I want to alter the output of the SELECT. I thougt i could do that with the Update.
   
The output should be a table with the value in the column there messung=1 and  Sensor=1
I need it to do some calculations direct in sql.

Comment: Well, you did not write this! You can perform any calculation within the select itself. Update statement is there to update the data within the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I have an solution for my problem i'm using an IF in the select now so that if messung=1 and sensor=1 the value of wert=1 is.
The Query looks like this

```
(Select messung, Sensor ,IF(messung=1 and Sensor=1,1,wert)as wert  FROM
      (SELECT A.messung,A.Sensor, A.wert FROM datenmatrix as A left join 
      (Select B.sensor FROM datenmatrix as B group by sensor) as C 
       on A.sensor=C.sensor where A.Sensor=1 order by Sensor) AS P);
```